# How do I get around this to be able to download the package Arules in rstudio?

Tags: r

[As you can see whenever I try to download the package it tells me to get rid of the set location but how do I do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mW3E.png)

I tried to change to where it downloads but it doesn't let me change it. So I have no clue on how to go around this.

Comment: You may get better help if you read these tips and edit your question accordingly: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) - good luck!

Comment: Did you try removing the file that it asks you to remove?

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/errors-updating-packages-failed-to-lock-directory-for-modifying-permission-denied-related-to-dll/73299

Answer (score -1):

you may have to remove (delete the folder) i.e., the OOLOCK, from the path that was mentioned in the screenshot, and try to install it again.